# Android different button styles depending on API level

Tags: android, button

I want to use the

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

for my buttons. This requires min. API level 11. I want my app to be min API level 9. So I used the styles tag in the default layout folder and createt the folders res/layout-v9 and res/layout-v10 with the same xml-files as in the default layout folder - except for the style tag. I still get the minimum API level 11 error for the XML file in layout folder.

How can I avoid the error and apply the style-tag for API level >= 11 but not for API level < 11?

Answer (score 1):

`borderlessButtonStyle` is part of the Holo theme, which is why it's not available below API Level 11.

You can however use that theme on earlier API levels by incorporating the [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) project into your app.

If that's not what you're looking to do, you'll need to create a custom selector in your drawable folders and use that for button styling instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the "Providing Alternative Resrouces" section in this article?:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Basically you add a suffix (called a "qualifier" in the linked article) "-v11" for specific API levels (so you would have a special folder named `layout-v10`, `layout-v9`, etc., each with the desired layout file in that folder).  I'm not sure if there's a way to specify a *range* of API levels, though (i.e., less than 11, vs. greater than 11).

Just as an aside: this is what's actually going on with providing differently sized icons with the same name: you'll notice that Android projects created in eclipse have `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, etc., as well as the "catch-all' `drawable` folders as a means for specifying alternative resources.